# flutter: got error when I add http dependency

Tags: android, flutter

I'm studying flutter networking in [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data). I totally follow the guidance but when I add http dependency then click `Packages get` then I get an error. What's wrong? Thanks for any advice.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  qrscan: ^0.2.17
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  http: ^0.12.2  // http dependency I added
```

the error info is below

```
Running "flutter pub get" in myProject...                        
Unexpected character (at character 1)

<html>

^

dart:convert                                       jsonDecode

package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 190:17          BoundHostedSource._fetchVersions

===== asynchronous gap ===========================

dart:async                                         _CustomZone.runUnary

package:pub/src/rate_limited_scheduler.dart 82:30  RateLimitedScheduler._processNextTask.runJob

package:pub/src/rate_limited_scheduler.dart 85:30  RateLimitedScheduler._processNextTask

dart:async                                         new Future.sync

package:pool/pool.dart 126:18                      Pool.withResource.<fn>

This is an unexpected error. Please run



    pub --trace '--verbosity=warning' get --no-precompile



and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
pub get failed (65; and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new)
Process finished with exit code 65
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the app?

Comment: @AdityaNigam I tried your advice, but unfortunately the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter

# The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
# Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
http: ^0.12.2  // http dependency I added 
qrscan: ^0.2.17
```

please write code in this sequence